# Inject custom system menu item and handler into newly opened windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, interop, com-interop

**What I want to do:**
I want to create a custom menu item (along with minimize, maximize, close, etc.) when a user right-clicks on a window's title bar. Additionally, I want the user to be able to click on my menu item and trigger my code. Also, I want to do this for every newly opened windows. For example, when the user opens up a new notepad window and right clicks on its title bar, he/she will see: Restore, Move, Maximize, Minimize, Foo (my menu item), Close. Once they click on "Foo", my code gets called.

**What I have so far:**
I am using SetWinEventHook to hook the EventObjectCreate event. I am also following [this guide](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ae59414e-579d-4d28-a3f8-bcb8badfee1b/adding-options-to-the-title-bar-menu?forum=vblanguage) to insert my own menu item (via GetSystemMenu and AppendMenu).

**My question:**
So now I can successfully inject my own menu item onto newly created windows, but nothing happens when the user clicks on the item. How do I register my function to this menu item when it gets clicked?

P.S. I'm doing this in C# using Pinvoke, not sure if this matters.

Comment: You are doing this for ***all*** windows opened on the desktop, regardless of who owns them? Or you're wanting to do this for windows opened by your application? If the former, C# is the wrong tool.

Comment: all windows opened on the desktop. I don't think using C# matters since I can just call native API using pinvoke?

Answer (score 2):

You have to hook the windows' window proc (also known as subclassing the window) and handle the [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) message. You check the `wParam` parameter and call your function if the menu item selected is your custom item.

You're going to run into interesting problems. See, for example, [Subclass a native application from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099546/subclass-a-native-application-from-c-sharp) and [Subclassing a external window in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554674/subclassing-a-external-window-in-c-sharp-net).

It can be done, but it's not simple.

You might also be interested in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3234/Subclassing-in-NET-The-pure-NET-way.